# Understanding deleting stateful sets

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

New to k8s. I want to understand, what `kubectl delete sts --cascade=false` does?

If i remove cascade, it deletes the statefulsets pods.

Answer (score 2):

It is clearly explained in the documentation under [Deleting the Statefulset:](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/delete-stateful-set/)

> Deleting a StatefulSet through kubectl will scale it down to 0,
> thereby deleting all pods that are a part of it. If you want to delete
> just the StatefulSet and not the pods, use `--cascade=false`.

So by passing this flag to `kubectl delete` the Pods that are managed by Statefulset are still running even though the `StatefulSet` object itself is deleted.

Comment: Yes I did read the k8s page but I still don't understand whats is meant by deleting statefulset? what exactly gets deleted?

Comment: Statefulset is an Kubernetes API object. It's way to tell the Kubernetes system 
how you want your cluster workload to look. When you create your object, cluster make sure that object exist and he is maintaining your desired state such a pod replicas, much like deployments do. With `--cascafde=false` you're just deleting the STS object in K8s API but the pods that K8s was maintaining for this pod are not deleted.

Comment: That's bookish definition which i did read. I want to see what exactly gets deleted when i say kubectl delete sts <sts-name>. Any idea?

Comment: I don`t quite get what is that you want here. What do you mean by see exactly?

Comment: If i delete po, or svc or pvc or pv or any other object i can see that it has been removed or re-created. how can i see whats deleted or re-created if i delete sts?

Comment: If you delete sts, nothing gets re-created. Pods running under sts and sts object gets deleted. You can check that its gone by using `kubectl get statefulsets`

Answer (score 0):

As described by [the fine manual](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/#non-cascading-delete), it deletes the `StatefulSet` oversight mechanism without actually deleting the underlying Pods. Removing the oversight mechanism means that if a Pod dies, or you wish to make some kind of change, kubernetes will no longer take responsibility for ensuring the Pods are in the desired configuration.

Comment: so what is oversight mechanism?